# Cannot change Main.storyboard's name on iOS 13 [Xcode 11 GM seed 2]

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, ios13

On iOS 13 simulator with Xcode 11 GM seed 2, the app crashes after `Main.storyboard`'s name changed (Info.plist changed also). Setting option `Main Interface` to empty cause the same problem. The iOS 13 system always try to find the `Main.storyboard`, and failed with crashing message:

```
*** reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle
```

**Everything is fine on iOS 12 and earlier versions.** It looks like a bug in iOS 13.

Does anyone meet same problem?  And any solutions?

Comment: Change it in `info.plist` file too

Comment: Are you sure the file is included in the build?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, the operations are all good, because the app is running on iOS 12.

Comment: if you again rename to "Main.storyboard" then it's working ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha, yes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Swift 5 with iOS 13**

> One more changes require in *info.plist* file under **Application
>   Scene Manifest** group.

[image]

Change name in **Application Scene Manifest** also.

**Additional:**
If you want to create the root window **without a storyboard** on iOS13, you need removing the `Main storyboard file base name` and `Storyboard Name` item from **Info.plist**, and then create the window programmatically in `SceneDelegate`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            //Do nothing here
        } else {
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        // continue to create view controllers for window
    }

    //......
}
```

Comment: I tried changing **both** occurrencies (as this answer says) but **it still doesn' work**: it crashes on `@UIApplicationMain`. I give up

Comment: @NicolasMiari, I updated the answer for programmatical way, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Main storyboard file base name` from `Info.plist` after you changed the name of `Main.storyboard`.And of course,you can change it from `General`-`Deployment info`-`Main Interface`.

Comment: The problem occurs with the right operations as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode rename Main.storyboard**

Just rename `UISceneStoryboardFile` string to a correct one in `Info.plist` file